# Run function every second Visual C#

Tags: c#, timer, draw

I have problems with timer.
I have function in function (draw in func)

```
void func(){

 /*...do something ... */
for(){
   for() {
  /*loop*/

 draw(A,B, Pen);

 }

/*... do something ...*/
  }
}
```

This is draw function

```
   public void draw1(Point Poc, Point Kra, Pen o) {
      Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
      g.DrawLine(o,Poc.X+4, Poc.Y+4,Kra.X+4, Kra.Y+4);
      g.Dispose();
      }
```

I call function 'func' on button click

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

    func();

}
```

I want to call draw function evry second (draw the line every second). 
Between drawings, function needs to continue working and calculate = loop, and draw next line for some time(interval). I tried with

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

etc..

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        draw(A, B, Pen)
    }
```

etc..

but all that stops my function, and draw one random line.
I just want the time(interval) between two drawings in function 'func'. Without timer works fine, but draw all lines immediately, I need slow drawing. 
Cheers.

Comment: your timer tick method should have `draw(A,B, Pen);` instead of `draw1()`

Comment: The timer is enabled?
Also add parameters to the function Draw1()

Comment: The parametars is Ok. Timer is enabled.

Answer (score -16, accepted):

SOLVED for now with

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
```

Answer (score 26):

I'm not ***entirely*** clear on what you're trying to do, but, in general, you can use an object of the Timer class to specify code to be executed on a specified interval. The code would look something like this:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
myTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 ms is one second
myTimer.Start();

public static void DisplayTimeEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // code here will run every second
}
```

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

aTimer.Interval = 1000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;       

//if your code is not registers timer globally then uncomment following code

//GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);



private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    draw(A, B, Pen);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't *draw* in a WinForms app, you respond to update or paint messages.  Do what you want to do in the form's `Paint` event (or override the `OnPaint` method).  When you want the form to be re-drawn, use `Form.Invalidate`.  e.g. call `Form.Invalidate` in the timer tick...