# Visual studio 2012 C# DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

In DateTime project, how can i get the hour ,min, PmAm so that I can put it inti Textbox  with using for loop ?

```
String dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
this.Text = dt;
```

Comment: What does Visual Studio or loops have to do with this?  Also, questions like this have been asked *many* times before. Did you search before asking?

Comment: i did and i couldn't find the answer

Comment: http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/017/674/rtfm_by_noptic.png

Answer (score 1):

Ok, This is my shortest and direct answer to your question.

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
this.Test = dt;
```

The following output will be `12:00:00 AM`

With For loop statement

```
for(int i = 0;i < 1; i++)
{
     string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
     this.Test = dt;
     i--;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be missing a for loop: quoting OP *with using for loop ?*

Comment: Great job using a loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

Is what you want based on what I understand. I would not use a for loop though to display it on your textbox. Use a Timer.Elapsed event instead: [Run function every second Visual C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954859/run-function-every-second-visual-c-sharp) (JeffFerguson's answer)